# asp.net mvc c# changing slug in child records

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

i have these records coming from my stored procedure which i am calling in linq to sql

```
int_PostTypeId  vcr_PostType    int_PostTypeId_fk   vcr_Slug       HLevel

  49                 c            36                    c             1

  77                 e            49                    c/e           2

  78                 f            77                   c/e/f          3

  79                 g            77                   c/e/g          3
```

i have these set of records.

suppose while editing the **int_PostTypeId** 49 i changed the **slug** to **c1**

1) now the slug in the child records also ought to be changed.

slug in 77 will become c1/e
slug in 78 will become c1/e/f
slug in 79 will become c1/e/g

2) if i edit the record 77 and change the slug to c/e2 then the slug 78 and 79 should also be changed to c/e2/f and c/e2/g.

so editing the slug in the record will change the child slug if exists. what is the most appropriate and efficient way of doing it in linq. i am taking the recursive loop path but i think that is highly inefficient. any idea for more general approach? or any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're actually updating a column called `vcr_Slug` in a record somewhere, rather than building the column's value in your stored procedure. Since you're actually using a stored procedure, why not calculate the column's value? I'm not sure if you're using a recursive common table expression to select your results, but if you are, it could take the form of something like the following (making some assumptions about your table structure which may not, of course, be completely representative):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPostTypes(@ParentTypeID int)

RETURNS TABLE

AS RETURN

(

WITH CurrentPostTypes(int_PostTypeId, vcr_PostType, int_PostTypeId_fk, vcr_Slug,
                      HLevel)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT pt.int_PostTypeId, pt.vcr_PostType, pt.int_PostTypeId_fk,
           pt.vcr_Slug, 1 AS HLevel
    FROM dbo.tblPostTypes AS pt
    WHERE pt.int_PostTypeId = @ParentTypeID
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT pt.int_PostTypeId, pt.vcr_PostType, pt.int_PostTypeId_fk,
           cpt.vcr_Slug + '/' + pt.vcr_Slug AS vcr_Slug, cpt.HLevel + 1 AS HLevel
    FROM dbo.tblPostTypes AS pt
    INNER JOIN CurrentPostTypes AS cpt
        ON pt.int_PostTypeId_fk = cpt.int_PostTypeId
)

SELECT *
FROM CurrentPostTypes

)
```

You'll notice in the recursive member definition where the previous value of `vcr_Slug` is suffixed with a slash and the current record's column value: `cpt.vcr_Slug + '/' + pt.vcr_Slug AS vcr_Slug`